# How shoud I structure the routes in react to make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting in React, and create a simple page Users and I would like to navigate between it and Home

```
| index.js
| components
|     App.js
|     Users.js
|     Home.js
|     Header.js
```

That's the structure that I defined:

Header.js:

```
<header>
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
    </BrowserRouter>
</header>
```

App.js:

```
< div >
     <Router>
          <Header />
           <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
     </Router>
 </div>
```

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It is not working, if I click in `<Link to='users' />` does not work, but enter in URL `localhost:3000/users` the pages is redirected.

### Solution

Remove `<BrowserRouter>` wrap from `Link`

```
<header>

      <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows

```
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/usuarios" exact component={Users}/>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
           


import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Users from './Users';
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                 <div className="links">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/usuarios">Users</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
)
}}
```

[Official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: I just tested this, I had to add `{BrowserRouter}` but even it did not work

Comment: If I enter `http:localhost:3000/users` it's work, but by clicking in `<Link />` did not work

Comment: @ThiiagoL you need to move `Header` to inside of `BrowserRouter` as you can only use `Link` inside of a router.

Answer (score 0):

**try move BrowserRouter in index.js file**

```
  ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
  );
```